# What's a reason behind not being able to host text tracks on a separate server than the actual page and is there a way to remove that limitation?

Tags: javascript, html, same-origin-policy, video.js

On video.js tag builder page (http://videojs.com/tag-builder/), it is stated that "Text files on a different server than the page aren't supported yet, i.e. your own files won't work in the test below but will on your own site."

What's a reason behind it and is there a way to remove that limitation?

PS: The hosting system I'm using stores all the assets files (images, css, js, text, etc.) on a separate server than the actual web pages.

Answer (score 1):

See ["same origin policy"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)
and ["ways to circumvent the same-origin policy"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy).